# Python function to read a text file into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file that contain the following lines:

> 103;1;2
>
> 103;6;2

Where the first item is the participant no., the second item is the lesson followed and the third item is the rate.

I want to combine the ratings of certain lessons in a dictionary.

This dictionary should have the participant number as key and a list of ratings belonging to that participant as value. There are 7 lessons in total. If the lesson is not taken, the rating in the list should be "NA".

So for the text file above, the function should return a dictionary as follows:

> {'103': [2.0, 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 2.0 , 'NA']}

How do I need to do this?

I have made a function that splits the items the way I want and creates a dictionary with the right key:

```
def ratings():

    dictionary = {}
    file = open("ratings.csv")
    for line in file:
        line = line.split(";")
        dictionary[line[0]] = []
    return dictionary
```

This code returns my dictionary as follows:

> {'103': []}

However, I do struggle with the value part of the dictionary I need to return, i.e. the list with ratings of each participant. How can I combine the ratings in one list and insert "N.A." if there is a missing value.

Comment: don't just post your homework task here.

Comment: You have a lot of options. Get inspired > https://www.vipinajayakumar.com/parsing-text-with-python/ < Good luck!

Comment: You need to start making some attempts at coding and then posts the failures (with code examples here).  I would start by googling "Python string parsing to list" -- that should give you some places to get started.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework without any effort

Comment: What's your understanding of the process needed to complete the task? What parts of the task have you tried to do yourself, and how? What parts don't you think you know what to do? Specifically what don't you understand about them?

Comment: I am sorry guys, I am not very familiar with using stackoverflow and Python. I tried to be more specific and edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
dictionary[line[0]] = []
```

You're telling Python that the value in that dictionary for the key `103` is `[]` which is empty.

You probably want something like:

```
def ratings():
    dictionary = {}
    file = open("ratings.csv")
    for line in file:
        line = line.split(";")
        if line[0] in dictionary: # already have some data for the participant
            dictionary[line[0]][line[1] - 1] = line[2] # minus 1 because Python is zero-indexed
        else: # new participant
            dictionary[line[0]] = ['NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA',]
            dictionary[line[0]][line[1] - 1] = line[2] # minus 1 because Python is zero-indexed
    return dictionary
```

Comment: Update: I just noticed the comments on OP's question about homework. Is this a homework assignment? If so, the community standards around how we treat it are a little different so please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/667758